# Kill process android clear singleton class data

Tags: android, kill-process

I have  two activity 'A' and 'B' with one  singletone 'S' class which is stored all data which I get from server in activity A now when I kill activity A after that when I singletone data on activity B while I used seperate process name for activity A and B, so why singletone data is null without killing whole application?

```
public class ContextSearch { 
    String title; List<FacetSearch> facetSearchs; 
    public ContextSearch() { }
    private static ContextSearch instance;
    public static ContextSearch getInstance() { 
    if (instance == null) { 
        instance = new ContextSearch(); 
    } 
    return instance;
} 
public static void setInstance(ContextSearch instance) { 
  ContextSearch.instance = instance; 
}
public String getTitle() { 
 return title; 
} 
public void setTitle(String title) { 
 this.title = title; 
}
```

Comment: can you describe it a little bit more ?

Comment: @RenjithKN thanks for reply, actually i have stored data in singletone class in activity A and when I switched activity A to B I am justing Killing Activity A throung process.killprocess("processname"); and when I get singletone class data on activity B its return null data i dont know what happening there i have create seperate process for both activity

Comment: please share the code of your  singletone class

Comment: @Narayan Soni edit ur question and post there.not in a comment.